# Sort entries according to number of occurrence in file

Tags: linux, file-io, awk

Some entries in my tab-del file are present singletons, some are paired and I would like to split my file according to the number of occurrence using some Unix command line.

Here is an example

```
1789:ST65:17  77 * ggfegZPPXX]][][_cbbcaefecbVcbb]aY^BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
1789:ST65:17  141 * ggbggggagedde^degdggaedebda`aedaaedcecdaa\bdSW\_T
1789:ST65:99  77 * ffcddcMdcdeebeeXecce_``]Pcfd]`aZ_bbK\`aUZZYP]`bb^b
1789:ST65:99  141 * gggggggegggfegggggg`ggeegebgfgeaggeedfeM^`K^`BBBBB
1789:ST65:173  77 * ggfegZPPXX]][][_cbbcaefecbVcbb]aY^BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
1789:ST65:201  77 * eacegZPPXX]][][_cbbcaef121cacc]aY^BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
1789:ST65:201  141 * ggbggggeeacaaadggaedebda`aedaaedcecdaa\bdSW\_T
```

In this simple case, I would like to have a first file paired-entries containing

```
1789:ST65:17  77 * ggfegZPPXX]][][_cbbcaefecbVcbb]aY^BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
1789:ST65:17  141 * ggbggggagedde^degdggaedebda`aedaaedcecdaa\bdSW\_T
1789:ST65:99  77 * ffcddcMdcdeebeeXecce_``]Pcfd]`aZ_bbK\`aUZZYP]`bb^b
1789:ST65:99  141 * gggggggegggfegggggg`ggeegebgfgeaggeedfeM^`K^`BBB.
1789:ST65:201  77 * eacegZPPXX]][][_cbbcaef121cacc]aY^BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
1789:ST65:201  141 * ggbggggeeacaaadggaedebda`aedaaedcecdaa\bdSW\_T
```

and another file containing only the singletons:

```
1789:ST65:173  77 * ggfegZPPXX]][][_cbbcaefecbVcbb]aY^BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
```

I tried to use `uniq` or `awk` but I am lost now. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: please post some new input using even more complicated text in the last column to make it even harder for us to tell what you want as right now it's only ALMOST impossible. Had you used small simple words like "foo" and "bar" in there it would just have been insulting.

Comment: It was clear enough to me, the last column isn't import for the comparison. Split the output base on duplicate's in the first column.

Comment: wouldn't it be nice, though, if the poster had stated that he was only interested in the first column and hadn't made the last column so complicated? Don't know about others, but there's only so much effort I'll put into trying to understand a question and if the OPs not putting any effort at all into phrasing it as simply as possible....

Comment: @EdMorton The example file is shown and the requested output is clearly described. Don't post sarcastic comments because **you** struggled to understand the question.

Comment: @sudo_o Perhaps I could have made the point without sarcasm but the point is valid and more useful long term to the OP than the posted solutions: if you're going to post a question, post sample input that's as simple as possible and describe WHY the posted output is what is desired. That way as many people as possible will be willing to take the time to read your question and give you an answer. It's not about struggling to understand the question, it's about not being inclined to put much effort into helping someone who hasn't put in the minimum effort to state the question clearly.

Comment: @EdMorton I think my question was easy to understand since I obtained several answers. BTW, I did put the "minimum effort" in copying/pasting and simplifying my file : The original file has 15 columns ...

Comment: You got 3 answers and one of them was mine and I understood what the question was from reading the first responses you got, not from reading your posted question. There's usually at least half a dozen people respond to these types of questions with various shell, perl, awk, etc, answers but if @sudo_o hadn't taken the time to figure out what you were asking, you may not have gotten any answers at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `uniq` to do this:

```
# Duplicates 
$ uniq -D -w 13 file.txt > duplicates.txt

1789:ST65:17  77 * ggfegZPPXX]][][_cbbcaefecbVcbb]aY^BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
1789:ST65:17  141 * ggbggggagedde^degdggaedebda`aedaaedcecdaa\bdSW\_T
1789:ST65:99  77 * ffcddcMdcdeebeeXecce_``]Pcfd]`aZ_bbK\`aUZZYP]`bb^b
1789:ST65:99  141 * gggggggegggfegggggg`ggeegebgfgeaggeedfeM^`K^`BBBBB
1789:ST65:201  77 * eacegZPPXX]][][_cbbcaef121cacc]aY^BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
1789:ST65:201  141 * ggbggggeeacaaadggaedebda`aedaaedcecdaa\bdSW\_T
```

---

```
# Singletons 
$ uniq -u -w 13 file.txt > singletons.txt

1789:ST65:173  77 * ggfegZPPXX]][][_cbbcaefecbVcbb]aY^BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
```

Options:

`-u` print all unique lines

`-D` print all duplicate lines

`-w` compare no more than N characters

---

*Note: this has a flaw if the columns aren't aligned and the different between the longest and shortest string in the first column is greater then 1 (given the two spaces between column one and two).*

A simple solution is to use `column -t` to align the columns:

`column -t file.txt | uniq -u -w 13 > singletons.txt`

Just remember to increase `-w 13` to `-w L` where `L` is the length of the longest string.

Answer (score 3):

One way using `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { array[$1]++; next } { print > (array[$1]==2 ? "pairs" : "singletons") }' file.txt file.txt
```

Contents of file called 'pairs':

```
1789:ST65:17  77 * ggfegZPPXX]][][_cbbcaefecbVcbb]aY^BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
1789:ST65:17  141 * ggbggggagedde^degdggaedebda`aedaaedcecdaa\bdSW\_T
1789:ST65:99  77 * ffcddcMdcdeebeeXecce_``]Pcfd]`aZ_bbK\`aUZZYP]`bb^b
1789:ST65:99  141 * gggggggegggfegggggg`ggeegebgfgeaggeedfeM^`K^`BBBBB
1789:ST65:201  77 * eacegZPPXX]][][_cbbcaef121cacc]aY^BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
1789:ST65:201  141 * ggbggggeeacaaadggaedebda`aedaaedcecdaa\bdSW\_T
```

Contents of file called 'singletons':

```
1789:ST65:173  77 * ggfegZPPXX]][][_cbbcaefecbVcbb]aY^BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
```

Answer (score 1):

A one-pass approach with awk:

```
awk '
!seen[$1]++ {
   solo[$1] = $0 ORS
   next
}
{
   print solo[$1] $0 > "pairs"
   delete solo[$1]
}
END {
   for (key in solo) {
      printf "%s", solo[key] > "singletons"
   }
}
' file
```